# Why Is This Column Name Invalid?

Tags: invalid-object-name

The code below results in the error (On Line 25):

> Invalid column name: FileDate.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDB.dbo.#CriminalCases') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CriminalCases

SELECT cc.CourtCaseID, cc.CaseDisplayNumber, cc.FileDate

into #CriminalCases
FROM (SELECT CourtCaseID, CaseDisplayNumber, FileDate, EndReasonID FROM dbo.CourtCase 
        WHERE NOT (CaseCaption LIKE 'BAD %' OR CaseCaption LIKE '%ERROR%' OR CaseCaption LIKE '%VOID%')
        and FileDate >= '2010-01-01') AS cc
    INNER JOIN dbo.CourtCaseSubType ccst ON cc.CourtCaseID = ccst.CourtCaseID
    INNER JOIN dbo.CaseSubTypeCodes cstc ON ccst.CaseSubTypeID = cstc.CaseSubTypeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.CaseTypeCodes ctc ON cstc.CaseTypeID = ctc.CaseTypeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.CaseCategoryCodes ccc ON ctc.CaseCategoryID = ccc.CaseCategoryID AND ccc.BenchID = 1 ---ccc.CaseCategory = 'Criminal Case'
WHERE (cc.Endreasonid not in (SELECT reasonID from dbo.RptExcludeReasonCodes) or cc.EndReasonID is NULL)
    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT DISTINCT crc.CaseDisplayNumber as MultiDefCriminalCases2010Forward, crc.FileDate --Why is this invalid? 
from #CriminalCases crc
INNER JOIN dbo.CaseAction ca on crc.CourtCaseID = ca.CourtCaseID
INNER JOIN dbo.PartyCaseActionRole pcar on ca.CaseActionID = pcar.CaseActionID
INNER JOIN dbo.PartyRoleCodes prc on pcar.PartyRoleID = prc.PartyRoleID and prc.PartyRole = 'Defendant'
Where (pcar.EndReasonID not in (SELECT reasonID from dbo.RptExcludeReasonCodes) or pcar.EndReasonID is NULL)
Group by crc.CaseDisplayNumber
Having Count(pcar.PartyCaseActionRoleID) > 1
```

The field `FileDate` is in the select statement. So why is it invalid on line 25?

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` on one column in your `SELECT` statement, so the other columns need to be aggregates. Try `MAX(crc.FileDate)` or similar?

Comment: Also, if this is SQL Server, please add the appropriate tag. If it's not, please tag your RDBMS.